# how to round the button of a dropdown list

Tags: css

How can I give the button of a dropdown rounded corners, by using just css?

By "the button of a dropdown" I mean this :

[image]

As you can guess I rounded the dropdown by using  CSS like `border-radius:5px;`

But what about the button? How can I make it rounded? With just CSS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure it's possible across browsers.. pretty sure you can use a background image though.

Comment: What browsers/versions are you trying to support exactly?

Comment: @jameslafferty Tricky question. The majority of them unfortunatelly. And of course mobile browsers also :(

Comment: Doing it with css isn't going to be an option. There's a project to do a jquery-ui selectmenu widget that might help: https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui.git

Comment: There is not a pure CSS solution, I usually use the uniform.js plugin to decorate select radio buttons, etc http://uniformjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if your wanting a custom arrow, your not going to be able to achieve it with pure CSS.  Your going to need some jQuery to help you out, with CSS influence styling.

Google will provide a numerous amount, however, I prefer jQuery SelectBox

[jQuery SelectBox](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/)

```
//Stack forces me to use code, click above ^^
```

If you need any help customizing that, just say so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add Rounded corner or Remove it in CSS. Just use the below tag

border-radius: 5px !important;

Here, above 5px makes the corner round and 0px can make to drop down corner Square .
And ! important is used to override the pre-defined value of the border-radius tag